# images of footnotes are not appearing in pop up window in epub

Tags: epub

I am doing epub-3(With footnote pop-up option) and I have used images in footnote section. When I am checking with Ipad, the images are not appearing in the pop-up window. The following is the coding and screenshot of iPAD view.

[image]

Screenshot of an iPAD
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the Ebook Q&A site. "Can anyone help me with this?" only has two valid answers: "Yes" or "No". Better to ask what you are doing wrong (or for that matter anything else that is not about the capabilities of people frequenting this site). Also, please be so polite to read the help->tour, before further posts, it clearly states no chit-chat  should be included in a good question (like the thanks you included).

Answer (score -1):

Use "object" tag instead of "img" and image extension should be .svg.